# Api platform + mercure. How to modify a published entity when mercure service is not working

Tags: symfony, server-sent-events, api-platform.com, mercure

Well, I cannot figure out how to proceed if the mercure service (hub) is not working in the server. If this happens, I don't mind updates to subscribed clients, but I need the api to work as expected if mercure was not present. But if I switch off mercure hub and I try to make a put to a mercure tracked entity I'm getting a 500 error. How can this be avoided? In other words, how could I get the tracked entity work if, by any reason, hub is down?

I expected to have a setting or something like that in CaddyFile or api platform mercure bundle to avoid this.

Comment: Would you create an asynchronous command to send the event?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sorry, not really sure what you're talking about. I use an EventSourcePolyfill from the front, and I can close it if the answer is an error. The problem is in the API when doing anything that alters the tracked entity.